# image slider working right to left , but not left to right i cant do that

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in programming.
I've  an image slider using  HTML and CSS and using JavaScript.
I have a problem with this script for displaying slides i want to display from right to left
The problem is, that the sliding is working from right to left, but not right to left.

Here's the code:

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");
// console.log(slides);
var counter = 0;

sliders.forEach((slide, index) => {
  slide.style.left = `${index * 100}%`;
//   slide.style.bottom = `${index * 100}%`;
});

const nextSlide = () => {
  if (sliders.length == counter + 1) {
    counter = 0;
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
  transformSlide();
};

const previousSlide = () => {
  if (counter == 0) {
    counter = sliders.length - 1;
  } else {
    counter--;
  }
  transformSlide();
};

const transformSlide = () => {
  sliders.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.style.transform = `translateX(-${counter * 100}%)`;
    // slide.style.transform = `translateY(${counter * 100}%)`;
  });
};
```

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sliders{
    width: 80%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px grey;
    position: relative;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    
    transition: 1s;
}

.nav{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.nav button{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(72, 71, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 20%;
}

.nav button:hover{
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav button:active{
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 220);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <title>Slider of Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sliders">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/320/1200/600" class="slider">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/321/1200/600" class="slider">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/322/1200/600" class="slider">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/323/1200/600" class="slider">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/324/1200/600" class="slider">
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <button onclick="previousSlide()">Previous</button>
        <button onclick="nextSlide()">Next</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is working as you expecting(for both sides). So what's the problem

Comment: Man it runnable... what is not working with it?

Comment: I want the slide image work frome left to right now it's work from right to left